# getting DuplicateDetector error in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, debug, dmlexception

[image: Debug Log]

I am getting the error seen in the above log. Why am I getting this error while trying to create a `Account` record from a `Visualforce Page`?

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED

Comment: Please share your code, but by the above screenshot it displays that your validation is checking for the comma in Name and the entered record contains a comma so this error is thrown.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any relevant text. -1 for image only log.

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar validation is pass.no issuse with the validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce's standard duplicate rule feature causes that issue.
You can see the name of the rule as Standard Account Duplicate ....... in the middle of the debug.

Let me give you the id of that rule : 0Bm36000001v4Wb :)

[image: quick find]

[image: here is the rules]

[image: deactivate button]

Comment: can we edit the rule,can we ,made it inactive

Comment: If you have privilage Yes.
It has deactivate button on detail view.

Comment: can u tell me the name of the button.

Comment: You can see the screenshots under my first answer